# How to update a NSStausItem from another file?

Tags: swift, macos, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I want to update the button.title property of a NSStausItem in the status bar, when the user klicks a button in my settings view. However, the NSStatusItem currently does not change.

AppDelegate:

```
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.variableLength)

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    statusItem.button?.title = "A title"
}

func updateTitle(newTitle : String) {
    statusItem.button?.title = newTitle
}
```

SettingsViewController:

```
@IBAction func didKlickChange(_ sender: Any) {
    AppDelegate().updateTitle(newTitle: "Updated title")
}
```

When I run the app the StatusBar show a new StatusItem with the title "A title". So good, so far.
But when I klick on the button, the only thing that happens is that a new status item appears for a very short time next to the old status item. The old one does not get updated.
Is there a proper solution for that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change NSStatusItem out of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653330/how-to-change-nsstatusitem-out-of-class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppDelegate()` creates a brand new instance of the class which is not the instance you expect. You need the actual reference

```
@IBAction func didKlickChange(_ sender: Any) {
    (NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate).updateTitle(newTitle: "Updated title")
}
```